# How to pass state in React from index.js to child elements without using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, state, state-management

I have a sample `React` app which shows projects on home page. I have created components as `Index` > `Projects` > `Project`:

My code in `Index.js`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Projects/>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

My code in `Projects.js`:

```
export class Projects extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            projects: [
                {
                    name: "Smithsonian Institute",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net//max_1200/da.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Beauty Inc Next Dimension",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/15d.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Beyond the Pale Blue Dot",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/5e22.jpg"
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Project data={this.state.projects} />
        );
    }
};
```

My code in `Project.js`:

```
export class Project extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="projects bg-ash">
                {this.props.data.map((item,i)=>
                    <div className="container work-item" key={i}>
                        <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                                <a href=""><img src={item.img} className="img-fluid rounded" alt={item.name}/></a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 image-box">
                                <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                                <p>{item.desc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </section>
        );
    }
};
```

I need to have this `this.state = { projects: [] }` data object in `index.js`and pass it through `Projects.js` to `Project.js`.

Main goal is to **manage state without Redux**. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Thanks @CKE It helped

Comment: I don't see a Projects component in index.js.

Comment: @N.Safi Yeah, it's corrected. Thanks.

Comment: The best way to manage state is redux. Managing state without redux/flux means that you will have to keep local states and pass them manually as properties. That's about it. Also, the idea that a "project" component should have list of all "projects" means there is something very wrong with your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Just passing the state through props, not need Redux for that:

Example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5xq5v5r4l)

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      projects: [
        {
          name: "Smithsonian Institute",
          desc: "Description goes here",
          img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net//max_1200/da.jpg"
        },
        {
          name: "Beauty Inc Next Dimension",
          desc: "Description goes here",
          img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/15d.jpg"
        },
        {
          name: "Beyond the Pale Blue Dot",
          desc: "Description goes here",
          img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/5e22.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ListItem items={this.state.projects} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**ListItem.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Item from "./Item";

export default class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
          <Item data={item} key={index} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

**Item.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <li>
        <div>
          <h3>{data.name}</h3>
          <p>{data.desc}</p>
          <img src={data.img} />
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If we have four levels as Index > Work > Projects > Project, how does this code should be changed.?

Comment: With 4 or more levels its the same method. You pass the state.projects in a props called projects (or other) on WorkComponent then, you pass the props.projects on an another props called what you want on his child (ListItem in my example), etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually pass the props down.

```
<Projects
  projects={this.state.projects}
/>

<Project
  projects={this.props.projects}
/>
```

Redux is designed for such cases, when you find yourself merely passing and forwarding props.

As stated on their website, their motivation.

> Managing this ever-changing state is hard. If a model can update another model, then a view can update a model, which updates another model, and this, in turn, might cause another view to update. At some point, you no longer understand what happens in your app as you have lost control over the when, why, and how of its state. When a system is opaque and non-deterministic, it's hard to reproduce bugs or add new features.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, you need to use [liftStateUp](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) you can lift `projects` state to `index` then inside `Projects.js` pass projects as props to `Project.js`.

**Index.js:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newProjects: undefined;
    };
  }

  receiveFunction = (oldProject) => {
    this.setState({ newProjects: oldProject})
  }

        render() {
            return (
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Header/>
                        <Projects receiveState={this.receiveFunction} newProjects={this.state.newProjects} />
                        <Footer/>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Projects.js:**

```
    export class Projects extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            projects: [
                {
                    name: "Smithsonian Institute",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net//max_1200/da.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Beauty Inc Next Dimension",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/15d.jpg"
                },
                {
                    name: "Beyond the Pale Blue Dot",
                    desc: "Description goes here",
                    img: "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.net/5e22.jpg"
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    liftStateUp = () =>{ // call this function whenever you want to pass the state to parent component
    let projects = this.state.projects;
      this.props.receiveState(projects);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){ // you can fire liftStateUp when every change in projects state
        if(prevState.projects !== this.state.projects){
            this.liftStateUp();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Project data={this.props.newProjects ? this.props.newProjects : this.state.projects} />
        );
    }
};
```

> Note: `liftStateUp` function needs to fire so I used `componentDidUpdate` to listen if projects state changes then it will be passed to the index page or for example you can use `onClick` method, the important thing that you got the idea.